# Scala: Constraints on fields that are not always respected

Tags: scala, constraints, field

Give me some help, I just cannot solve this problem.
How do I ensure that constraints on getter methods are always respected?
My classes have this form:

```
abstract class Element {
  var name: String
  var description: String
}

class Component (var name: String, var description: String) extends Element
```

For the purpose of my project I need to use var.
I want to put constraints on the field `name` that must always be respected.
Both when I create an instance of `Component` as follows:

```
val C1 = new Component ("C1 Component", "Description of C1")
```

Both when I change the value:

```
C1.name = "new value"
```

If I create the classes in this way:

```
abstract class Element {
  protected var _name : String
  // Getter
  final def name = _name
  // Setter
  final def name_= (value:String):Unit =
    if (value.size < 5) println ("ERROR: Bad Value")
    else _name = value

  var description: String
}

class Component (protected var _name : String, var description: String) extends Element
```

In the main method, because I do not have control here:

```
val C1 = new Component ("C1", "Description of C1")
```

But only later, when I change the value:

```
C1.name = "comp"
```

I want my getter to always be respected.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Component (_name : String, var description: String) extends Element {
  this.name = _name
}
```

Also, make `var _name` private, so subclasses can't set it without using the setter.

Comment: It does not solve the problem. Plus: Error: class Component needs to be abstract, since variable _name in class Element of type String is not defined (Note that variables 
  need to be initialized to be defined)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it still gives me error. Error:"reassignment to val" for "this.name = name". 
If I put var _name as private, after I assign a value to her.

Comment: @user1826663 Then change the parameter name (see edited code).

Answer (score 1):

In Scala the entire class body makes up the primary constructor. So you can call the setter as the first part of your constructor. The syntax is in my opinion quite messy however. You could do something like this:

```
abstract class Element {
 var name: String
 var description: String
}

class Component (private var _name :String, var description : String) extends Element {
  name = _name
  def name = _name
  def name_=(value: String) = {
    require(value.size > 5, "Bad value")
    _name = value
  }
}
```

**However**. It is perhaps... unwise to have `vars` in the fashion you are using them. It is much better to use an immutable class and deal with copies of this class. So any time you need to modify that name field... just create a new Component object that's the same as the old one, with a different name. There are many ways you can achieve this (search for Lenses), but a simple way is to use the `copy` method provided on `case classes`. Here is an example:

We change the Component class to be a case class:

```
case class Component (private var _name :String, var description : String) extends Element {
  name = _name
  def name = _name
  def name_=(value: String) = {
    require(value.size > 5, "Bad value")
    _name = value
  }
}
```

And our usage looks like this:

```
val C1 = new Component ("Some component name", "Description of C1") 
//Component(Some component name, Description of C1)

val C2 = C1.copy(_name = "Another component name") 
// Component(Another component name ,Description of C1)
```

Comment: Hi, I have many classes that inherit from Element, then it would be nice to have a check in their Element.